# Controlling window placement in unity with twinview

Tags: unity, twinview, xinerama

I am running a system running Ubuntu Oneric where i have a DVI monitor and an HDTV as my screens.

They are set up using nVidia TwinView. The monitor and TV are not side by side and the intent is to drag movies to the TV and then full screen it. The problem is that windows often open on the TV which I cannot normally view while sitting at the computer. What is the simplest way to tell unity to open windows on a specific monitor exclusively?

Note that I have only 1 HDMI connector so swapping the cables for the TV and the monitor is not an option.

Note: It is not always opening in this way but eg. when a website open up a confirmation dialog it always opens on the TV.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried disabling the "Place windows" plugin in the Compiz configuration? This plugin was responsible for a similar issue in my two-monitor configuration.

See also [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83277/how-do-i-force-applications-to-open-on-the-correct-monitor/100542).